# AWS S3 get return object referenceID/Unique ID after save an object

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

im trying to get return unique ID of stored object in AWS S3 bucket, is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

AWS S3 is effectively a key/vaue store, where the file name is the unique key per unique bucket.

Maybe you may find useful the [ETag](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTCommonResponseHeaders.html) header which is a hash of the content